# What is the difference between these cases of using interface vs type in typing the keys of an object?

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between the three cases below:

```
type RowDataKey = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

type RowData = { [k in RowDataKey]: number }

type RowData2 = {
  prop: number, 
  [k in RowDataKey]: number
}

interface RowData3 {
  prop: number,
  [k in RowDataKey]: number
}
```

Also, this is also an error:

```
interface RowData4 { [k in RowDataKey]: number }
```

How is this different from the first case above?

In particular why do the two last cases give an error? RowDataKey being used as value not a type in those last two is the error.

The goal is to be able to have all the keys from `RowDataKey` plus an additional property `prop`, so I can do like this:

```
const rowData: RowData = {
  one: 1, two: 2, three: 3
};

const rowData2: RowData2 = {
  prop: 1,
  one: 1, two: 2, three: 3
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

A mapped type has a specific syntax `{ [ TypeParameter in KeyUnion]: PropType }`. You can't add anything else to that. You can't add `prop` separately.

If `prop` is always of the same type as the other props, you can just `RowDataKey | 'prop'`:

```
type RowDataKey = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

type RowData = { [k in RowDataKey | 'prop' ]: number }
type RowData2 = Record<RowDataKey | 'prop', number> // same thing, with predefined types
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=89&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwCIENgoNIRFAvFAcjgDsICoAfQ4BOcqg4ACwCcIyBuAKC9ElkSp0eKAG8oAbQDWUAJbEByNJmyVCYFnDDkAugC4oxAK4BbAEYQWUAL69w0eEvQAmETAgBjOCwAmAHkchFRwGDS0CABpDUwsWAD4oAHpEqABnFBNoZnkAcyiEWWYoDQgfCAAzeVKoPghUriA)

Or if the type of `prop` is different you can use an intersection type:

```
type RowDataKey = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

type RowData = { [k in RowDataKey]: number } & { prop: string}
type RowData2 = Record<RowDataKey, number> & { prop: string} // same thing, with predefined types
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=98&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwCIENgoNIRFAvFAcjgDsICoAfQ4BOcqg4ACwCcIyBuAKC9ElkSp0eKAG8oAbQDWUAJbEByNJmwBdAFxRiAVwC2AIwgsoAXygAyMVDAs4YTQGdgLeQHMTvcNHhL0AJhEYCABjOBYAEwAeHyEVEAAaLT1DFgA+CysbO0dnNzMAenyoBxRdaGY3RIRZZms2cIgAM3kIcKg+CAcuIA)